# Sending search term from view to service via controller in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search

I am having a hard time understanding search in rails. I want to send search term from my view to service. I have this code in my service:

```
class Searching
    def search_term
        drive_auth.list_files(q: "fullText contains 'term'",
                              spaces: 'drive',
                              fields: 'nextPageToken, items(id, title)')
    end
end
```

And this code in controller:

```
class SearchController < ApplicationController
  def index;  end
  def show
    //here I should take term from search box and send to 
      search_term in service instead of word 'term'
  end
end
```

And this is my view (I understand it's not full code, that's why I need help)

```
<p>
  <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
  <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
</p>
```

What I want is to search from index.html.erb and show results in show.html.erb page on click. How to send this parametar to search method in service and show results in html?

Comment: You can use the Ransack Gem for search. This is just a suggest. https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack

Comment: What is your issue actually? Or you don't how to send `params[:search]` to the search service?

Comment: Yes, I don't know how to send it to service. How should I do that?

Comment: @beginner17: I have added my answer, let clarify whether this code can resolve your issue or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to send `params[:search]` to from your controller to service, below code may solve your issue:

In controller:

```
class SearchController < ApplicationController
  def index;  end
  def show
   result = Searching.new.search_term(params[:search])
   # Your code to use result
  end
end
```

In service:

```
class Searching
    def search_term(q)
        drive_auth.list_files(q: "fullText contains '#{q}'",
                              spaces: 'drive',
                              fields: 'nextPageToken, items(id, title)')
    end
end
```

Comment: It's working when I change q: q, to q: "fullText contains '#{q}'". Thanks! Howewer it's working when I pass q from code. Can you help me now make search button work on click, to actually show these results? If not, thanks for you help anyway. :D

Comment: I don't know that the query need to contains `fullText contains`. I updated the query according to your feedback. Do you have the search page already or you have to write it from scratch?

Comment: I managed to do that by myself! :D Thank you so much for you help.

Comment: If you have this page already. Please post another question with your code and problem so that it easier to discuss and answer.